# Context Menu Glitch

Tags: windows, contextmenu, windows-10

I'm having a problem with the contextual menu (right click menu) on Windows 10. It seems that the item text disappears sometimes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Other time, the menu itself doesn't work at all.

[image]

I've googled for answers but none of the suggested solutions worked. One thread that seems to describe the same problem was this one:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/3fejwo/windows_10_context_menu_glitch/

So I'm hoping (though it might be cruel to do so) that someone else have encountered the same problem and might have a solution for this annoying bug.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions. The [help] has more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like GDI has run out of resources. Open Task Manager, go to the Details pane and show the GDI Objects column and see if any process has more than a few hundred.

...or it's a GPU driver glitch, try using a different driver version. In a worst-case-scenario your physical GPU might be damaged, try using your internal GPU (Intel HD Graphics) and see if that helps.